# WordPress | Upload files and resize them

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have develop a script that allowing the registered front end users to create their own posts, with a featured image for each post.

While I have complete the overall process, the problem now is the image resizing.

The script that manipulating the images is the following:

```
if(isset($files['rcp_user_logo']) && $files['rcp_user_logo']['error'] == 0)
{
    $uploadDir      =   wp_upload_dir();
    $updoadBase     =   $uploadDir['basedir'];
    $uploadURL      =   $uploadDir['baseurl'];
    $uploadLogos    =   $updoadBase . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'LfirmLogos' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $uploadLogosURL =   $uploadURL . '/LfirmLogos/';
    $dir_exists     =   false;                          //  Flag for directory existance

    if(($dir_exists = is_dir($uploadLogos)) == false)   //  If the upload dir is not exists
    {
        $dir_exists =   mkdir($uploadLogos, 0755);      //  Try to create the dir with 0755 permissions
                                                        //  If the dir will be successfully created
                                                        //  the $dir_exists will be set to true
                                                        //  otherwise will be set to false
    }
    else
    {
        $dir_exists = true;                             //  If upload dir exists then set
                                                        //  the $dir_exists to true
    }

    if($dir_exists  == true)
    {
        //  Set the tmpFile to the temporary uploaded file path
        $tmpFile    =   $files['rcp_user_logo']['tmp_name'];
        //  Set the new file to upload directory and name the file after the custom post ID
        $newFile    =   $uploadLogos . $new_id . '-' . $files['rcp_user_logo']['name'];
        //  Set the new file URL to updaload directory URL and name the file after the custom post ID
        $newFileURL =   $uploadLogosURL . $new_id . '-' . $files['rcp_user_logo']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, $newFile))      //  If file has been
        {
            $wp_filetype    =   wp_check_filetype($files['rcp_user_logo']['name']);

            $attachment = array(
                'guid'           => $newFileURL,
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => sanitize_title($files['rcp_user_logo']['name']),
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );

            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $newFileURL, $new_id);

            if($attachment_id != 0 )
            {
                if(!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'))
                {
                    include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                }

                $attachment_data    =   wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $newFileURL);
                $result = wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
                $result = update_post_meta($new_id,   '_thumbnail_id',    $attachment_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** In order to keep me logos seperated from the default WordPress images I have create my own catalog under the /wp-content/uploads/ and I don't know if that is a reasong to prevent the image resizing.

**NOTE :** $new_id is the ID of the post created in the previews code programmaticaly.

**NOTE :** I also have used the plugin "AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild" but still no effect on the images. It cannot resize the images too.

**NOTE :** Images that are uploaded by the admin area, are properly resized.

Is there any idea on how to solve that issue ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you using php's GD images since wordpress uses it as well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Here is a code snippet taken from that page that resizes the image to a percentage, 0.5 in the example:

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

**Note:** AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild it's a plugin that rebuilds the thumbnails from the wordpress media manager.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this is not the proper way of image resizing for WordPress images, because WordPress keeps archive for the resized images, it has a special way to name the files, can manipulated those images and so on.

Comment: So basically you want to integrate your thingy with the wordpress media library? I don't really get what you mean, except resize images :S

Comment: My media are already integrated with the WordPress media library. The problem is that the images I uploading, are not resized for some reason. While images I uploading for other posts from the backend are properly resized.